# What is the (single) best online source for learning OpenOffice.org scripting API

Tags: api, scripting, openoffice.org, uno

I am using OpenOffice.org for most of my not so very frequent Office Suite needs and most of the time it is more than adequate replacement for it's commercial alternative.

Where it falls short though is the scripting API. I am yet to find the documentation that would make sense of the API in a way that would let me concentrate on my task at hand instead of wandering how to select a piece of text in an opened document.

So - is there a good documentation for getting programmers like me, who do not exactly live and breathe the UNO object model, quickly started and explain in few pages or less, how to find stuff that I need in the OO.o API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're specifically talking about working with text documents, that section of the OO.org Dev Guide really is the way to go:

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Working_with_Text_Documents

Note that the document navigation is on the right side, and kind of small.  There's similar entry points for Spreadsheets:

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Working_With_Spreadsheet_Documents

And for drawing documents:

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Drawings/Working_with_Drawing_Documents

I think this is the kind of general "cheatsheet" reference you're looking for and I don't think there's any better source for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the [OpenOffice.org Developer's Guide](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide)

Comment: This looks like a nice comprehensive guide to OpenOffice.org development.

What I'd like to see is some documentation that is more narrowly focused towards scripting specific applications (Write, Base, Calc, etc.)