# Best way to create a form in OpenOffice (or sth else?)

Tags: scripting, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I'm looking for a way to script an OpenOffice document so it would:

- have only parts editable
- do some magic with saving it (i'd like to save it into some generated from the entered content name)
- be reasonably easy to implement

I've looked into this question:
[What is the (single) best online source for learning OpenOffice.org scripting API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261318/what-is-the-single-best-online-source-for-learning-openoffice-org-scripting-api)

and it seems helpful, however I can't find other things to be easily done.

I'd be grateful for help in this matter.

Marcin

Comment: I hate to say it but I think in order to meed your requirements the OpenOffice API is the easiest way.

Comment: perhaps You are familiar with some other solution that would suffice my needs, without learning new programming API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is something that would suffice without a lot of hassle. This would be XForms, described here:

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Using_Forms_in_Writer

This does pretty much anything I assumed it should.